# Why can't I access children on three.js group?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this class

```js
class GameManager {
  constructor() {
    this._activeObjects = new THREE.Group();
  }


  get randomGeometry() {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

    return geometry;
  }

  get randomMaterial() {
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: "red",
      wireframe: true,
    });

    return material;
  }

  spawnCube(scene) {
  
    const newCube = new THREE.Mesh(this.randomGeometry, this.randomMaterial);
    this._activeObjects.add(newCube);
   
   
    scene.add(newCube);
  }

  animateObjects() {
    this._activeObjects.children.forEach((obj) => {
   
     obj.position.z += 1
    })

  }
}

export const gameManger = new GameManager();
```

Once I actually attempt to render these cubes and animate them.

```js
  
gameManger.spawnCube(scene);
 
(function animate() {

  gameManger.animateObjects()

 
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

})();
```

The cube renders just fine but the `_activeObjects.children` only has the added cube within the scope of the `spawnCube` method. If i try to access it from `animateObjects` it's empty.

Shouldn't this retain reference to the same group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  spawnCube(scene) {
  
    const newCube = new THREE.Mesh(this.randomGeometry, this.randomMaterial);
    this._activeObjects.add(newCube);
   
   
    scene.add(newCube);
  }
```

Here, you do `.add()` twice. But an object can't have two parent objects, thus it will be removed from children of the previous parent on the second `.add()`.

See the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.add

And what it does internally: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L306L348